# sqlitejdbc.dll.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run on a new Windows 10 machine my build I get a failing build with the below message:

```
C:\Windows\room-1986fd87-5a68-4d98-8d52-10725d43f799\sqlite-3.20.1-13332950-0c44-4e15-b974-b3790f5ede28-sqlitejdbc.dll.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run as administrator did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Windows 11, after upgrading to Java 17 (required by Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0).

The solution (workaround) that worked for me, was migration to KSP, i.e. replacing:

```
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1")
```

with

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1")
```

This solution also requires adding KSP plugin to `plugins` block:

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.20-1.0.10"
}
```

Comment: Setting the Gradle daemon to use a JDK 11 also fixes this problem, as a temporary fix without having to use KSP.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove kapt.use.worker.api = true from gradle.properties